# Pandas pivot returns NaN value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pivot

I have the following table:

```
CODE      VALUE          FIELD  INDEX
AR002     012014          001    001
AR002     2343244,29      002    001
AR002     1214124,19      007    001
AR002     1001            011    001
AR002     16022024        014    001
```

I need to obtain the following output:

```
001     002         007           011       014
012014  2343244,29  1214124,19    1001     16022024
```

So, for each CODE and INDEX, I need to create the columns based on FIELD. I try with the method pivot() from Pandas, but it gives me the following output:

```
df.pivot(columns='FIELD', values='VALUE')
```

```
001     002 003 004 007 008 009 010 011 013 014
012021  NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
1   NaN 2343244,29  NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
2   NaN NaN NaN NaN 1214124,19    NaN   NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
3   NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN 1001    NaN NaN
4   NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN 16022024
```

Comment: Do yo mean `df = df.pivot(index=["CODE", "INDEX"], columns="FIELD", values="VALUE")` ?